# When run react-native run-android for run emulator adb android studio, show error app:installDebug FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, adb

When run react-native run-android show error :

```
Task :app:installDebug FAILED
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the application was already installed in the emulator, I deleted the emulator application and it worked